# Highcharts stacked column ommit smaller values

Tags: angular, highcharts

The screenshot below represent the same series.
In the stacked column version (chart on the top of the screenshot), small values are missing (but exists in the serie), while they are visible in the area chart (chart on the bottom of the screenshot).

What could possibly be wrong (using the latest version on Highcharts - 3.0.0) ? Bug ?

Note

series = [0, 29, 7, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 28, 9013, 7204, 6729, 12360, 5897, 9302, 11335, 8754, 12829, 5326, 911, 17, 73, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1739, 2515, 1075, 451, 578, 457, 331, 260, 555, 730, 575, 462, 452, 423, 409, 308, 263, 285, 209, 187, 98, 58, 39, 16, 20, 0]

[image: columnDoseStackedChart.data]

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason: the values are just too small to be displayed.
Unfortunately, a mouse over won't show at least those values.

Setting the `clip` option to false solve partially the problem.

```
      this.columnChartOptions.plotOptions = {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          clip: false
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly noticed - the values are just too small to be displayed. A good solution can be to set `minPointLength` and use `null` data vales insted of 0. For example:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 5,
    stacking: 'normal',
    data: [...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ly1fkzdh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.minPointLength